# Convert json to csv NoneType issue

Tags: python, json, csv

I have met an issue when convert json to csv below is my return list

```
msg=[{u'qALang': None, u'endDate': u'2019-12-03 16:06:28', u'language': u'EN', u'surveyId': u'SV_71AcgFo76QeXKiV', u'personId': u'666666', u'question': u'Q0', u'responseId': u'R_3I5D24ShIyrVo79', u'startDate': u'2019-12-03 16:05:46', u'surveyType': None, u'emailAddress': None, u'answer': u'1', u'finishStatus': u'1', u'responseSet': u'Default Response Set', u'surveyReference': u'test_vvvv', u'camsLeadId': u''}, {u'qALang': None, u'endDate': u'2019-12-03 16:06:28', u'language': u'EN', u'surveyId': u'SV_71AcgFo76QeXKiV', u'personId': u'99999', u'question': u'Q1a', u'responseId': u'R_3I5D24ShIyrVo79', u'startDate': u'2019-12-03 16:05:46', u'surveyType': None, u'emailAddress': None, u'answer': u'10', u'finishStatus': u'1', u'responseSet': u'Default Response Set', u'surveyReference': u'test_vvvv', u'camsLeadId': u''}]
```

```
ls=json.loads(msg)
csv_file = open(OutputCsvPath, 'a+')
csv_data = []
for item in ls:
    csv_data.append(list(item.values()))
for line in csv_data:
    csv_file.write(",".join(line) + "\n")
csv_file.close()
```

And it will return error msg

> sequence item 3: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found

I know `",".join(line)` use is not correct but how to avoid?

Comment: `msg` isn't JSON. JSON is a string, `msg` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You should use the `csv` module to read and write CSV files.

Comment: Did you mean to say that that list is the value of `ls` rather than `msg`?

Comment: i have done json.dumps then json,loads then using wite , but i want know how to convert this dict to csv file,thanks!

Comment: msg=json.dumps(msg, ensure_ascii=False) then json.loads(msg)

Comment: It's confusing to use the same variable for different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `join()` have to be strings, but some of your values are `None`, e.g. `u'surveyType': None`. You need to convert all the values to strings.

```
for line in csv_data:
    csv_file.write(",".join(map(str, line)) + "\n")
```

Comment: You can also use `",".join(str(x) for x in line)` if you're more familiar with that.

Comment: today i have ran this program again , find through out UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'\u76e1\u8cac', 0, 2, 'ordinal not in range(128)')   seems using str not right and how to using  utf-8 instead